# Read raw data from socket

Tags: delphi, sockets

I have a device that sends data to my server via gprs . The problem is that it sends raw data and i don't know where i can stop the reading

Currently i am using something TIdHttpServer and something like this to read the strings :

```
var
    s : string;
    repeat
       s:=s+acontext.Connection.Socket.ReadChar;
    until acontext.Connection.Socket.InputBufferIsEmpty;
```

Is there a better solution to my problem ?

Comment: What protocol is being sent?  Does the device just close the connection after each protocol unit?

Comment: No it mantains the connection open for me to send commands. Is a custom protocol based on TCP / IP

Comment: Why don't you use `AContext.Connection.Socket.ReadLn` ?

Comment: @TLama because i don't know with what character the string will end

Comment: opcode, you mean you have a description of which commands to send, but no information about the response ?

Comment: @opc0de: please show an example of the actual data being sent.  There has to be a structured protocol to it, otherwise no GPRS receiver would know when to stop reading.

Answer (score 3):

TCP is stream oriented. If the protocol is unknown, the server only can try to read into a byte array (if memory is not a problem) or a file stream. If the client disconnects normally, the data is 'complete'. Unfortunately, if the protocol is unknown, the server can not tell wether the client died or disconnected normally.

InputBufferIsEmpty does not help, as it only says if there is data in the (TCP) buffer - and depending on latency this can happen frequently, but it does not mean that there are no more in-flight bytes.

You could try to 'reverse engineer' the protocol, by sending known strings over the client devices. But if the sender is a black box, there can be many special cases - think of encoding or 'escape' characters etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could make up you own protocol.

Some ideas are:

1. use a special character or characters combo to define the end of the
   message.
2. append at the start of the message some fixed size field with the size of the message